# How can I split all buttons in a container into two columns in HTML?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a HTML Script with a continer and 10 buttons in it. how can i split them in two columns as in the image I've added?

This is my Code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <button style="height: 100px;">Btn. 1</button>
  <button style="height: 80px;">Btn. 2</button>
  <button style="height: 120px;">Btn. 3</button>
  <button style="height: 90px;">Btn. 4</button>
  <button style="height: 100px;">Btn. 5</button>
  <button style="height: 120px;">Btn. 6</button>
  <button style="height: 85px;">Btn. 7</button>
  <button style="height: 95px;">Btn. 8</button>
  <button style="height: 105px;">Btn. 9</button>
  <button style="height: 110px;">Btn. 10</button>
  <button style="height: 85px;">Btn. 11</button>
</div>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvG31.png):

[image]

[How it should lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwo51.png)

[image]

I've tried it with Grid and with Flexbox, but I wasn't able to solve the problem.